# Как привязать окно tkinter к окну стороннего приложения?

Tags: python, tkinter

Уточнение вопроса:

1. необходимо привязать окно tkinter к окну стороннего приложения
2. по возможности сделать встроенными средствами python
3. привязка к активному запущенному окну приложения например КОМПАС-3D
4. привязка поверх окна, но не поверх всех окон (возможно ли такое?)
5. сократить время отклика, чтобы не было тормозов
6. какие есть альтернативы?

Работающий пример:

```
import tkinter as tk
import win32gui

kp = []
i = 0

def callback(hwnd, extra):
    global kp, i
    name = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    if name.find('КОМПАС-3D') != -1:
        if i == 1:
            kp = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.lift()
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
root.after_idle(root.attributes, '-topmost', True)
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(bg='#F2F2F2', highlightthickness = 1, highlightbackground='#666666', highlightcolor='#666666')

def update_position():
    try:
        while True:
            win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, None)
            w = 28
            h = 100
            ki = 147
            root.geometry(f'{w}x{h}+{kp[2]-w-2}+{kp[1]+ki}')
            root.update()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        root.destroy()

update_position()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @insolor, есть мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: блин, забыл, как сделать обращение к пользователю на форуме, через собачку?

Comment: Мысли есть, вероятно можно встроить свое окно внутрь чужого окна с помощью WinAPI (но это не точно), но у меня Linux, и в целом лень разбираться.

Comment: а какие модули за это отвечают, не в курсе?

Comment: Что-то из win32api. Нужно гуглить именно встраивание средствами WinAPI (на C/C++), потом пробовать переложить это на python + tkinter.

Comment: Можно ли встроить сортировку сразу при запросе hwnd, дабы сократить ресурсы? например по имени  приложения, и необходимым параметрам (4 позиции окна), выполнить сортировку по активности окна?

Comment: нашел такое: https://coderoad.ru/8302225/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-windows-%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85

Comment: и тут меня заинтересовало: Попробуйте выбрать элемент управления и поиграть с его свойством "Dock". С помощью этого вы можете прикрепить элемент управления к некоторым сторонам или даже ко всем сторонам родительского элемента управления. Можно ли сделать привязку через Dock в python?

Comment: Наткнулся на одну библиотеку: https://github.com/yinkaisheng/Python-UIAutomation-for-Windows